# How to handle java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am getting `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException` exception while trying to load images in `ImageView`.This is not occurring every time but occurring in sometime.I know why the problem happens but don't know how to handle it.

```
    public void onPostExecute(HttpResource[] httpResources) {
            if (httpResources != null) {
                String imageUrl = httpResources[0].getUrl();
                File imageFile = httpResources[0].getFile();
                int count = 0;

                ArrayList<ImageItem> list = map.get(imageUrl);
                if (list != null) {
                    //TODO implement pagination or manage concurrent threads
                    for (ImageItem imageItem : list) {
                            ImageHelper.loadImage(context, imageItem.getImageView(), imageFile, imageItem.isAutoResize(), imageItem.isAutoOrientation(), CROP_LAYOUTS_PARAMS);
                    }
                }

                map.remove(imageUrl);

                if (map.isEmpty()) {
                    LogHelper.i(LibConst.TAG, "HttpImageProvider cache is empty");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: load image asynchronously with callback on success or failure trigger remove item from map.You can use glide or any other image loading library for this.

Comment: use image loading library like Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide or Universal Image Loader or picaso. They all handle such tasks very efficiently.

Comment: @TheAnkush Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. I will try one of those and will see how things work out. But how to handle this exception in general.